# How can I fix this parallax animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web development.

I'm doing this animation with a sprite that allows you to move the image when the user scrolls or up. The problem is that the image shakes when I scroll. How can I fix this bug?

`

```
var rotator = $('#rotator');
var container = $(document);
var viewport = $(window);

var images = 10;
var imageHeight = 5930 / images;
var scrollHeight = container.height();
var position = images/scrollHeight;


viewport.scroll(function(event) {
    rotator.css('background-position', (-position) + 'px 0');
    if(position < 5930) {
        position = position + imageHeight;
        if (position >= 5930) {
            position = 0;
        }

    } else {
        position = 660;

    }
});
```

`

Comment: By setting `diff` to `595` (the actual width of every single image) and using it by declaring the position it’s nearly smooth: https://jsfiddle.net/ye4tx0u1/29/

Comment: Thank you very much. @KitMedia.It's working perfectly